# How do I get the certificate key pair from Key Vault to import into Windows Server?

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

A certificate was imported into Azure Key Vault. How do I download and install it on Windows Server?

The problem is when the certificate is downloaded manually there is no password.

My questions are:

- How to download the certificate from the Key Vault in powershell.
- Next (since we know the certificate when downloaded from the Key Vault
  has no password associated) How install the certificate into Windows Server via powershell?  Pssession or otherwise?

**when manually downloading the cert it doesn't work. also the password is blank.**

been using:

```
$vaultName = "SomeoneBusiness"
$certificateName = "SomeoneDotcom"
$exportFilePath = "C:\MyCert\YourCertificate.pfx"  # Define export file path including filename and extension
$certificatePassword = "SuperSecret"  # Password used to protect the exported PFX

# Get the certificate from Azure Key Vault
$certificate = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName

# Export the certificate to a .pfx file with password protection
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certificate.Certificate -FilePath $exportFilePath -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certificatePassword -AsPlainText -Force)
```

However it doesn't download or create a Certificate.pfx

Next need to place a task in azure release pipeline in classic mode to release the "certificate.pfx" onto the windows server and import.
Ideas?

Am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Accordingly to Microsoft's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/how-to-export-certificate?tabs=azure-cli#export-stored-certificates) Key Vault doesn't save the associated password, that's why it is blank. And you could also have a look at the example they've provided to download the PFX using Powershell and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

`Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate` will never download the private key; that is, you'll never get the key pair. Also, when you import it, you must provide the password. The private key is decrypted using the password when stored in Key Vault, so even when you do get the key pair, the private key is already decrypted. You also need to make sure the certificate policy allows exporting the private key. The default policy will allow exporting, but if you need to change it, you have to do it first before importing a new version of the certificate: the policy is for the *next* version, or the version being added by `Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate` (not relevant in this case, but may help in the future).

To demonstrate, consider you have a PFX (PKCS12) file with the private key encrypted. To import it:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'hunter2' -AsPlainText
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName myvault -Name mycert -FilePath mycert.pfx -Password $password
```

To get the private key - which, again, which already be decrypted - you need to get the managed secret which happens to have the same name as the certificate:

```
$cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName myvault -Name mycert
$cert.Certificate.HasPrivateKey # False

$encoded = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName myvault -Name mycert -AsPlainText
$cert2 = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new([Convert]::FromBase64String($encoded))
$cert2.HasPrivateKey # True
```

Note that if the private key is not exported when you import the certificate or create a new one in Key Vault, the managed secret will not contain the private key - only the certificate.

If you want the private key to be exportable after you import it into the local machine (not recommended), change the `X509Certificate2::new` constructor call to:

```
$cert2 = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new([Convert]::FromBase64String($encoded), $null, 'Exportable')
```

If you want to automate installation of the certificate into the machine store, make sure you're running this script in an elevated process and you can do so right from within PowerShell without exporting to a file:

```
# Or use a different StoreName below rather than "My" as appropriate.
$store = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new('My', 'LocalMachine', 'ReadWrite,OpenExistingOnly')
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

The certificate has now been imported.

If you want to save it to a password-protected file, you can use:

```
$cert.Export('pfx', $password) | Set-Content mycert2.pfx -AsByteStream
```

Then you can import the file into the certificate store using `certmgr.msc`, `certutil.exe`, or any number of tools.

Comment: Running: 
$store = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new('My', 'LocalMachine', 'ReadWrite,OpenExistingOnly')
$store.Add($cert2)
$store.Close()

getting "access is denied" even using elevated powershell.